# Angularjs CRUD | Data Comparing at View

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am creating an app in **Angularjs** where I am unable to compare **JSON data in View** of the application. Code is as under :-

**JSON is as under** :-

```
data = [
 {"name":"Anand","score":[{"subject":"PHP","marks":88}]},
 {"name":"Deep","score":[{"subject":"html","marks":77}]},
 {"name":"Sachin","score":[{"subject":"html","marks":77}]}
]
```

I want to show this JSON data as depicted in below diagram :-

```
Name\Subject | PHP  |  HTML   |  Java
--------------------------------------
Anand        | 80   |  60     |  --
Deep         | 70   |  --     |  --
Sachin       | 55   |  56     |  45
so on ...    | --   |  --     |  80
--------------------------------------
Min Marks    | 70   |  56     |  45
Max Mark     | 80   |  60     |  80
```

**Angular View code** is below :-

```html
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="sub in subjectDataSet">{{sub}}</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="sub in subjectDataSet">
    <td ng-repeat="data in marksheet">{{data.score}}</td> 
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Please help me to represent data.
Waiting for your response!!

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: I am unable to print data as required and mentioned in upper defined table format. Please help

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh you have quite a few decisions to make when it comes to how this should be built. In your JSON it seems that not all people have all subjects, if that's the case then you have to repeat each student, and then you have to repeat each subject - not for that student, but for the entire "class", or whatever it is. Please have a go, if you're still stuck then add your controller/service(s) code as well

Comment: what is `marksheet`? it's not part of 'sub`

Comment: @charlietfl - I am saving entire data in marksheet variable

Comment: @JimL - I have already tried but not able to show data as per above view. I have created one more array after filtering the main array and get the subject name and then print the same in <th> but in <td> not able to print the same as its print data row wise. If possible can you please help to print the same